# install clodufiy3.4 at centos7 error occured

Tags: cloudify

I installed cloudify3.4 according to the cloudify DOCS. When I install the manager, and executed like this:

```
# cfy bootstrap --install-plugins -p openstack-manager-blueprint.yaml -i openstack-manager-blueprint-inputs.yaml
```

an error occurred:

```
[ERROR] Workflow failed: Task failed 'nova_plugin.keypair.creation_validation' -> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I have already installed

"cloudify_openstack_plugin-1.4-py27-none-linux_x86_64-centos-Core.wgn"
"cloudify_openstack_plugin-1.4-py27-none-linux_x86_64-redhat-Maipo.wgn"
So, how to solve this error? Thank you to everyone who helped me!

Answer (score 1):

The error says you have a problem with your keypair definition.

Please check if you have defined a wildcard or something that is not valid for keypairs.